# XML deserialize iso 20022 pain.001.001.03 from xsd using c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, deserialization, xsd.exe

I want to get an object from an xml file. In my example I am using iso 2002 pain.001.001.03

[image: ISO 200022 pain.001.001.03]

I have downloaded the schema from

[pain.001.001.03.xsd](https://www.iso20022.org/documents/messages/1_0_version/pain/schemas/pain.001.001.03.zip)

and the xml file from

[pain.001.001.03.xml](https://www.iso20022.org/documents/messages/pain/instances/pain.001.001.03.zip)

I have validated my xml against the xsd using this tool

[Validate XML](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)

I have generated a class using xsd

[image]

and I am using the code below in order to deserialize

```
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerCreditTransferInitiationV03),    new XmlRootAttribute                             
                     { 
                         ElementName = "Document",
                        Namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03",
                   });


           FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("C:\\001.001.03\\pain.001.001.03.xml", FileMode.Open);

           CustomerCreditTransferInitiationV03 myObject = (CustomerCreditTransferInitiationV03) ser.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

The code return null values but my xml has values

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
```

The root element is an `Document`, and not a `CstmrCdtTrfInitn` :

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var document = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(file);
    var transfer = document.CstmrCdtTrfInitn;
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code and It returns this message "Error en el documento XML (50, 7)" in the inner exception returns "{"La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto."}". I am trying to fix that before I check yout answer as a correct one.

Comment: @EduardoUstarez I didn't have any problem deserializing the document from the link you provided. I can try look into the problem if you provide the exactly class definitions, and the xml (if you are using a different one).

Comment: It seems like a weird problem. The xml at line 50 is `<EndToEndId>ABC/4562/2009-09-08</EndToEndId>`. The exception indicated there is a format issue, however it is being deserialized into a `string` (`PaymentIdentification1.endToEndIdField`).

Comment: Yes, it is weird but I am working on other xml and it works so thanks for your answer.